# Why can't I return a concrete type in a function that has a polymorphic return type?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass

For example, why isn't it possible to define a function like -

```hs
fun::a
fun = 1

-- OR

someInt::Int
someInt = 3

fun::Num a => a
fun = someInt
```

It seems like this is possible in Java -

```java
class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SomeClass().hello().sayHi());
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    Hi hello() {
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }
}

interface Hi {
    String sayHi();
}

class A implements Hi {
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi from A";
    }
}

class B implements Hi {
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi from B";
    }
}
```

but the equivalent in Haskell does not work -

```hs
main = print $ sayHi hello

hello:: Hi a => a
hello = A

class Hi a where
  sayHi::a -> String
  
data A = A
data B = B

instance Hi A where
   sayHi _ = "Hi from A"
   
instance Hi B where
   sayHi _ = "Hi from B"
```

I'm trying to understand the fundamental difference between interfaces in Java and typeclasses in Haskell? What are the limitations and benefits of each approach?

Comment: In Java it's not possible either: `public static <A> A fun() { return 1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common misunderstanding.

Polymorphism works completely different in Haskell compared to OO languages. (Though many of these languages have a templating / generics feature that is more comparable to Haskell's polymorphism.)

In Java, polymorphism is based on *subtyping*: by defining an interface `I`, you define a (large, abstract) type, and a class that instantiates this interface defines a subtype of `I`. So, a Java interface isn't fundamentally different from a Java class – indeed, in C++ interfaces and classes use the same `class` keyword; Java merely places some sensible restrictions on how each can be used.
That means polymorphic functions don't really need to do anything else from ordinary functions: they just have a signature that refers to the type `I`, which includes any subtype. So if `I` is supposed to be the result type, the implementor has the freedom to return any subtype.

In Haskell, there is no such thing as subtypes<sup>†</sup> (though there are ways to emulate them). Typeclasses don't define types at all (but rather *sets of types* instead; the distinction is important for much the same reason it's important to make a distinction between e.g. integers and lists of integers). So they can't appear in signatures the same way as types would. Haskell polymorphic functions really do work entirely different from monomorphic ones, and the signature actually expresses this quite clearly:

```
fun :: Num a => a
```

says that `fun` first takes an (implicit, type-level) argument `Num a`, and then produces a value of type `a`.

...Actually even a bit more is happening: the full form of the above signature is

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForall, UnicodeSyntax #-}

fun :: ∀ a . Num a => a
```

which says basically it takes *two arguments*:

- It first takes a type, `a`
- It then takes a dictionary, `Num a`, which explains how it is possible to use `a` as a number type
- And it then yields a value of type `a`. That is, *the exact type* `a`, not some subtype or whatever.

When calling `fun`, you don't need to explicitly pass either of these arguments, the compiler can do that for you, but it does need to be clear what particular type it should be. You *can* explicitly pass the type argument, that's what the [type applications syntax](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html) is there for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

fun :: ∀ a . Num a => a
fun = 37 + 9

main :: IO ()
main = do
   print (fun @Int)  -- prints 48
   print (fun @Float)  -- prints 48.0
```

... not to be confused with `(fun :: Int)`, though that has in this example exactly the same effect: here, the compiler infers from the context that `a` must be the type `Int` because that's expected as the result, whereas `fun @Int` explicitly instructs the compiler to use `Int` and not allow it to adapt to the environment.

This way of doing polymorphism gives the caller a lot of power, but of course the flip side is that the callee needs to support all that generality by supporting all the types that the caller could possibly request.

It's not usually a big problem, just don't try to squeeze Haskell code into the mindset you would have in a language like Java. A class or interface in Java often corresponds best to a simple `data` structure, or indeed just a value of an already existing type, not any typeclass.

For your example, why not just use:

```
data Hi = A | B

sayHi :: Hi -> String
sayHi A = "Hi from A"
sayHi B = "Hi from B"
```

What I've done here is basically just declared `A` and `B` as something analogous to subtypes of the type `Hi`, right there and then – not by first defining `Hi` abstractly and then post-hoc populating it with subtypes, but by saying up front that `Hi` consists of both `A` and `B`.

Alternatively, if you want to keep `Hi` *open*, i.e. want to allow people downstream to customize it in unforseen ways... well, then it's also completely unforseen what kinds of strings you get, so what's the point of having a type-level abstraction at all? You might just as well take the strings as arguments as they are, which makes it even simpler:

```
sayHi :: String -> String
sayHi x = "Hi from "++x
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>To be precise here: in Haskell, *Rank-0 types* do not have subtypes. A rank-0 type is what could also be described as a concrete type, whereas higher-rank types have quantors in them. Higher-rank types do have subtypes (basically, by quantifying over different classes). But it's kind of begging the question, because a rank >0 type has polymorphism already built in, as it were.</sub>

Comment: "In Haskell, there is no such thing as subtypes" Isn't that a little too absolute? I though you could treat, for example, the polymorphic type `a` as a subtype of any concrete type (or at least, a less constrained polymorphic type).

Comment: @chepner I considered to write "there is no such thing as a subtype of a Rank-0 type" but decided not to, lest I confuse novice readers further than they already are at this point. But yeah, it should in principle be there.

Answer (score 5):

With the function:

```
hello :: Hi a => a
hello = A
```

You promise the user of the function that the *user* can pick *any* `a` they want, as long as it is an instance of `Hi a`. So this means the user could use:

```
hello :: A
hello :: B
```

But this is not what your implementation is showing: it will always return an `A` object. In that sense the type constraints in object-oriented programming (Java) and functional programming (Haskell) are somewhat each others "reverse". In Java you promise that it will be *a* subclass of `Hi`, in Haskell you promise it can return a value that is *any* type of the `Hi` typeclass.

Your `hello` is thus simply:

```
hello :: A
hello = A
```

if you then use `hello` in a function that promises it can work with any `Hi a => a` item, like:

```
sayHi :: Hi a => a -> String
```

it will thus unify `a` with `A`.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd translate your Java code as follows:

```hs
main = putStrLn (sayHi (hello SomeClass))

data SomeClass = SomeClass

hello :: SomeClass -> SomeHi
hello SomeClass = SomeHi A

class Hi a where
  sayHi :: a -> String

data SomeHi = forall a. Hi a => SomeHi a

instance Hi SomeHi where
  sayHi (SomeHi x) = sayHi x

data A = A

instance Hi A where
  sayHi A = "Hi from A"

data B = B

instance Hi B where
  sayHi B = "Hi from B"
```

But this is not idiomatic code. You probably shouldn't need to write code like this very often.